# rxjs: extract slice of a collection given start and end matching rules

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to write a reactive function with rxjs that, given a potentially infinite array:

- Rule 1: Skip initial null items
- Rule 2: Extract the items between two '*' appearances
- Rule 3: If first item after nulls is not an '*', must fail (or return an empty array)
- Rule 4: Process no more than N items
- Rule 5: If there's no a second '*', must fail (or return an empty array)

So, with N = 10:

```
Case 1: [null, null, '*', 1, 2, 3, '*', 4, 5] -> [1, 2, 3]
Case 2: [null, null, 1, '*', 2, 3, '*', 4, 5] -> [] // Breaks rule 3
Case 3: [null, null, '*', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, '*'] -> [] // Breaks rule 5 (second * is at position > N)
```

For the case 1, there's no problem. But I don't find the set of operator to enforce the rules 3 and 5

This example illustrates the problem:

```
const { from } = require('rxjs');
const { take, takeWhile, skipWhile, toArray } = require('rxjs/operators');

function *infinite(items) {
  for (let i = 0; ; i++) {
    yield i < items.length ? items[i] : `fake${i}`
  }
}

const extract = ({
  source,
  limit = 10,
}) => new Promise(resolve => {
  source
  .pipe(...[
    take(limit),
    skipWhile(item => item === null),
    skipWhile(item => item === '*'),
    takeWhile(item => item !== '*'),
    toArray(),
  ])
  .subscribe(result => {
    resolve(result)
  })
})

;(async () => {
  console.log(await extract({ source: from(infinite([null, '*', 1, 2, 3, '*', 4, 5, 6])) }))
  console.log(await extract({ source: from(infinite([null, 'a', '*', 1, 2, 3, '*', 4, 5, 6])) }))
  console.log(await extract({ source: from(infinite([null, '*', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])) }))
})()
```

Edit: I realized the operation:

```
skipWhile(item => item === '*'),
```

is not accurate. Should be something like

```
skipThisSingleItemIfMatchAsteriskOtherwiseFail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution for your problem is the following. Comments are inline

```
function extract(c: any[], n: number) {
  // first you create an src stream where all the leading nulls are removed
  const src = from(c).pipe(
    // just take the first n elements
    take(n),
    // filter to remove the nulls - this can be a problem if you have nulls between the 2 '*'
    filter((item) => item !== null),
    // share is used to avoid having more than one subscription to this stream
    share()
  );

  const core = src.pipe(
    // here we consider all elements until the second '*' is met
    // And what about the first '*'? see the rest of the code, there is the explanation
    takeWhile((item) => item !== "*", true),
    // create an array which cumulates all the values received until the stream completes
    toArray(),
    // if the array of all elements received is empty or if the last element is not a '*' return []
    // else return the elements received a part the last '*'
    map((arr) => {
      return arr.length === 0
        ? []
        : arr[arr.length - 1] !== "*"
        ? []
        : arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1);
    })
  );

  // this is the stream returned by the extract function
  // it starts from the src stream we have created above
  return src.pipe(
    // the first element is taken
    // since the src stream is shared between this stream and the stream we have called "core" and have built above
    // then it means that the first element is consumed here and will not be encountered in the "core" stream
    first(),
    // if the first element is not a '*' an error is thrown
    tap((d) => {
      if (d !== "*") {
        throw new Error("First not null val is not *");
      }
    }),
    // if no error is thrown then we return the stream "core"
    concatMap((firstItem) => {
      return core;
    }),
    // if an error is thrown then we return an Observable which emits []
    catchError((e) => of([]))
  );
}
```

In order to use this function you can write the following code

```
const resp = extract(source, 10);
resp.subscribe((d) => {
  // do stuff with the result, for instance
  console.log(d);
});
```

[Here a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-w15vi1?file=index.ts) that reproduces this logic

Comment: Thanks! That's just the approach I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How about something with custom RxJS operators? Try the following

```js
const { Observable, from } = rxjs;
const { take, filter, reduce } = rxjs.operators;

const onlyIfFirst = predicate => {
  let first = true;
  return source =>
    new Observable(subscriber =>
      source.subscribe({
        next(value) {
          if (first) {
            first = false;
            if (predicate(value)) {
              subscriber.next(value);
            } else {
              subscriber.next([]);
              subscriber.complete();
            }
          } else {
            subscriber.next(value);
          }
        },
        complete() {
          subscriber.complete();
        }
      })
    );
};

const toArrayWhen = (predicate, count) => {
  let id = 0;
  let times = count * 2;
  return source =>
    source.pipe(
      reduce((acc, curr) => {
        if (!!id) {
          if (predicate(curr)) id++;
          if (id < times && !predicate(curr)) {
            acc = [...acc, curr];
          }
        } else {
          if (predicate(curr)) id++;
        }
        return acc;
      }, [])
    );
};

const input = [null, null, '*', 1, 2, 3, '*', 3, '*', 4, '*'];

from(input)
  .pipe(
    take(10),
    filter(value => value !== null),
    onlyIfFirst(value => value === '*'),
    toArrayWhen(value => value === '*', 1)
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: value => console.log('Next:', value),
    error: error => console.log('Error:', error),
    complete: () => console.log('Complete')
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.2.2/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Note: I'm fairly certain the `count` variable behavior for `> 1` is buggy at the moment. But as long as you only need the first instead of values between two asterisks `*`, it should be find.

Comment: Excuse me for not explaining the code. I'll try to explain if I find some time later.